# Using SVG image in WPF project as Canvas background

Tags: wpf, svg, canvas

I need to use an SVG file in my WPF project, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (mandatory).
My goal is to be able to drag and resize some rectangles over the SVG, as I need to know the rectangles' position the first simple solution is to use the SVG file as a `Canvas`' background and then insert some `UserControl` inside the `Canvas` so the user can do his things. The final appearance should be something like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYAvM.png)

Unluckily this solution is not possible because SVG isn't supported in `Canvas` and WPF. I tried to convert the file to others format (XPS, pdf, png...) but with no success, I tried using WPF `WebBrowser` to visualize SVG but it's impossible to put something (the rectangles) over that control, I tried to generate a bitmap but with some problems with resolution, I tried also to use some library (open source mandatory) but I didn't manage to use them in my VisualStudio as NuGet and VS2012 lack of compatibility.

Could anyone suggest me a way to achieve this? Is there any workaround with any controls that I haven't thought about yet? Or using a library per SVG is the only way?